# Bootstrap modal on shown method run multiple times

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I use [twitter bootstrap modals](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)'s js to show and hide a modal:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')//show
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
// do something…
})
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
// do something…
})

....
$('#myModal').modal('hide')//hide
```

My problem is when show and hide modal multiple times, the code in `//do something...` run multiple times. I guess that's because every time i show a modal, it listen to `shown` and the function run 5 times when the modal hide and open 5 times, any way to prevent this?

---

Using the way `fco` suggested below did solve the shown problem, but unfortunately the hide does not work, i.e. still execute more than one times, one thing different, i hide the dialog using the `data-dismiss="modal"` markup, not through js.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think your problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706342/bind-different-events-with-same-name-to-single-object

Comment: You need to unbind the `shown` function if you only want it to execute the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/%20.off%28%29)

if you want the event handler to run only the first time you need to do something like:

```
function myHandler() {
    //your event handling code here
    $('#myModal').off('show', myHandler);
}
$('#myModal').on('shown', myHandler);
$('#myModal').modal('show');
//...
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you post, that works, but i also use a hide handler, still not worked as excepted using your way, i updated my post, could you please check it out?

Comment: I sloved this problem by let the register handler execute exactly once, not every time when showing a modal. Anyway good to know the the `off` method.

Answer (score 3):

You should use one instead of on

The  .one() method is identical to  .on(), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation. For example:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')//show
$('#myModal').one('shown', function () {
// do something…
})
$('#myModal').one('hidden', function () {
// do something…
})

....
$('#myModal').modal('hide')//hide
```